# numba `if condition` performance

Tags: python, performance, numba

I have this code

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit()
def build_permutations(position_length, starting_leverage, ending_leverage, iteration_size=100_000_000, starting_amount=100_000 ):

    sublist = np.zeros((100_000_000, position_length), dtype=np.int16)
    sublist_index = 0

    current_permutation = np.full(position_length, starting_leverage)

    while True:

        # Apply the filter condition
        sum_of_leverage = np.sum(current_permutation)
        if(sum_of_leverage > 20) and (sum_of_leverage <= 100):
           sublist[sublist_index] = current_permutation

           sublist_index += 1
           if sublist_index == iteration_size:
               yield sublist[:sublist_index]
               sublist.fill(0)
               sublist_index = 0

        # Generate the next permutation
        i = position_length - 1
        while i >= 0 and current_permutation[i] == ending_leverage:
            current_permutation[i] = starting_leverage
            i -= 1

        if i < 0:
            break

        current_permutation[i] += 1

    # Yield the remaining sublist if it's not empty
    if sublist_index > 0:
        yield sublist[:sublist_index]
```

changing the filter condition to be this

```
        call_leverage = 0
        put_leverage = 0
        for index, val in enumerate(current_permutation):
            if index_to_position_type[index] == 1:
                put_leverage += val
            if index_to_position_type[index] == -1:
                call_leverage += val

        max_leverage = max(call_leverage, put_leverage)
        min_leverage = min(call_leverage, put_leverage)

        if (min_leverage >= 35) and (max_leverage <= 40):
```

instead of

```
        sum_of_leverage = np.sum(current_permutation)
        if(sum_of_leverage > 20) and (sum_of_leverage <= 100):
```

slows it from around 1 second to around 90 seconds. In order to remove this, I have been thinking of paralellizing the function. Is there any reason adding this for loop + if condition would increase the time so much? The original filter was also summing the permutation, just without if's. Why would this take so much longer? Is there a way to index into another array with numpy's sum function, something like

np.sum(perm, where=index_to_position_type[{{perm_index}}]==1)

Comment: Please mention the Numba version, and add some data to get a full working example. The first try to improve performance would be to change enumerate to a for loop. Logically the same, but Numba has a known issue with enumerate: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/9038

Comment: You are testing timings after previous compilation? Also, I was thinking the same as max9111 that `enumerate` is a problem here, not `if`s.

Comment: i ended up removing the for loop completely and updating put/call leverage relatively and inline as the value in the permutations changed